# What is the best way to get a site visitor's location?

Tags: php, javascript, geolocation, ip-geolocation

After googling, I found many solutions that don't seem to work or require permission from the user.

Looking for something that is easy to use, PHP or Javascript, and does not require the user's permission. It doesn't need to be the most accurate.

Comment: see related questions to the right, this has been asked a lot

Comment: The best way? Ask them. Otherwise, use GeoIP, and be prepared for it to be enormously inaccurate in many cases.

Comment: With geoIP you will not get the exact location. Using HTML5 to utilize nearby Wifi Access Points to get more exact location requires user permission, and there is no way you can circumvent that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google Analytics is great for this (javascript).

EDIT:
Should point out that Google Analytics has an API to get City/Country info and all reporting info if you need to programmatically do something with it - http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/

But if that's not an option:

You can get a users ip with PHP's `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`

With that, you can use PHP's GeoIP library to geolocate it: http://php.net/manual/en/book.geoip.php

Comment: I cant find anything about obtaining and using GA to get city info from the Google link you provided above. Could you elaborate? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use (you can get IP by `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` and pass it to the function):

```
function GeoData($ip) 
    {   
        $Content    =       CurlGet("http://api.hostip.info/get_html.php?ip=" . $ip . "&position=true");
        $ContentArr =   explode("\n", $Content);

        $Stack      =   array();
        $Ctr        =   0;

        foreach($ContentArr as $Item)
        {
            if($Ctr == 2) 
            {
                $Ctr++;
                continue;
            }

            if($Ctr == 6)
                break;
            $SingleItemArr  =   explode(":", $Item);
            array_push($Stack, $SingleItemArr[1]);  
            $Ctr++;
        }

        $MappedStr      =   array("country" => $Stack[0], "city" => $Stack[1], "latitude" => $Stack[2], "longitude" => $Stack[3], "ip" => $Stack[4]);
        $JsonEncoded    =   json_encode($MappedStr);

        return $JsonEncoded;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's very important to point out that querying the GEO IP database from MaxMind via php is an excellent solution, if the site is going to have any amount of traffic beyond that of a personal site you are going to have to invest in a MaxMind license. Having had experience integrating MaxMind for high volume e-commerce retail sites, the cost can be quite significant (although the benefits in regards to payment systems is well worth it).

One more comment. GeoIP is only accurate to the general coverage area of the ISP's local DNS server that the user is connected to. It is not GPS. It generally does not get down to the street level. And, if the user is connecting through a proxy, VPN, etc, the data/info is useless.